# jwPlayer 6.8 and LiveRail Integration

Tags: jwplayer, liverail

We are using JWPlayer 6.8 (ad version) and need to integrate with LiveRail. However we seem to be having issues making this integration work. LiveRail doesn't seem to know what the issue is so I am coming here for some help.  In a nutshell: we have implemented jwPlayer according to the instructions given by LiveRail found here: http://support.liverail.com/publisher-integration/player-integrations/jw-player. We have embedded the player on our site and when we access it the default image and video play but there is no advertisement. LiveRail has verified that our account is good to go for receiving adverts however they don’t want to play.

Our jwplayer implementation looks like this:

```
  jwplayer("ad-container").setup({
    plugins: {
      'http://cdn-static.liverail.com/js/LiveRail.AdManager.JWPlayer-6.8.0.plugin.js' : {
        'LR_PUBLISHER_ID': '12345',
        'LR_AUTOPLAY': '0',
        'LR_CONTENT': '6',
        'LR_ADMAP': 'in::0',
        'LR_VIDEO_ID': 'testAdId1',
        'LR_TITLE': 'OurTestAdvert'
      }
    },
    primary: "flash",
    file: "http://cdn-static.liverail.com/swf/ui/uivideo.mp4",
    image: "http://cdn-static.liverail.com/swf/ui/uivideo.jpg",
    height: 250
  });
```

Can anyone at jwplayer confirm if this setup is valid? Also I note here (http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1434510-getting-started-with-jw-ads) that jwplayer ad setups can include an advertising section like this:

```
jwplayer('myElement').setup({
  file: 'assets/myVideo.mp4',
  image: 'images/myImage.jpg',
  primary: 'flash',
  advertising: {
    client: 'vast',
    tag: 'http://adserver.com/vastResponse.xml'
  }
});
```

Is this advertising section required when dealing with LiveRail?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you running this? Do yo have a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advertising section in the JW Player setup block is for our built in advertising. The LiveRail plugin is totally separate from this.